# Cannot connect to database server using mysql workbench under Debian 9

Tags: mysql, connection, debian

I've installed mysql server 5.5 in localhost under debian 9. When I open MySQL Workbench I cannot create a connection. When I try to create a connection an alert appears "cannot connect to database server. Access denied for user root at localhost"

I tried to access in mysql server using:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
```

And I use the password 'root' that I've before setted

Error 1968 appears and I don't know how to do.
Any Idea?